# jQuery when list item selected, add to current class div

Tags: jquery, list, if-statement, append

I have a jQuery drop down list for a language selector. At the moment i have a skeleton setup of how it works but i am quite confused to how to start the active jQuery function.

What i would like it to do is when the user clicks a language from the list, the language name (or in future the flag) will appear at the top in the "current div class".

The default that would be in the current class would be the english list item.

I am unsure how to start this but from research i have found that i could create an `if statement` and use the `append/prepend` elements? Am i going in the right direction?

I am using Codeigniter and created a language translator so inside of having html anchor tags my php is written like this:

```
<li id="french"><?php echo anchor('fr/'.strtolower($page_info['fr_title']), 'FR'); ?></li>
```

Here is a link to a rough prototype of how it is currently set up. Any tutorials or guidance would be appreciated.

If language is french display the french flag and so on:

```
$(function() {
    if ( document.location.href.indexOf('en') > -1 ) {
        alert('english');
    } else {
        if ( document.location.href.indexOf('ru') > -1 ) {
            alert('russian');
        }else {
            if ( document.location.href.indexOf('fr') > -1 ) {
                alert('french');
            }else {
                if ( document.location.href.indexOf('fr') > -1 ) {
                    alert('french');    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/Wmb4n/2/

Comment: checkout this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Wmb4n/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/Wmb4n/5/)

```
$('#lang_selector ul li').click(function () {
    $('.current').text($(this).text());    
});
```

**EDIT:**  Your `if.. else` statements need to be cleaned up.

```
$('#lang_selector ul li').click(function () {
    $('.current').text($(this).text());
var loc = document.location.href;
    if (loc.indexOf('en') > -1) {
        alert('english');
    } else if (loc.indexOf('ru') > -1) {
        alert('russian');
    } else if (loc.indexOf('fr') > -1) {
        alert('french');
    } else if (loc.indexOf('fr') > -1) {
        alert('french');
    }
});
```

Comment: Exactly thank you. This works within my code but it seems to flick on and then go back to saying current as i assume due to the page refresh (when the language is changed and the page changes to russian.) Is there a e prevent solution i could use on this div to stop it changing from page refresh. Thanks for the short example :)

Comment: @user2212564 I'm not sure but try this `$('#lang_selector ul li').click(function (e) {
    $('.current').text($(this).text());   
    e.preventDefault();  
});`

Comment: Tried that already and unfortunately it's not changing the page to russian or french. I have created a snippet in my code that i will add now to how i think i may get it triggered.

Comment: @user2212564 are you getting anything when you do `alert(document.location.href); `

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you want..

try it out..

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.current').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle();
});
    $('ul li').click(function(){
      $(this).parent().prev('span').text($(this).text());
    });
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/Wmb4n/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so **user1671639** answered my question above but another issue was that the page was refreshing with the new language content which meant that the selected div was flickering before page load. I also tried `$('#lang_selector ul li').click(function (e) { $('.current').text($(this).text()); e.preventDefault(); });`

Which kept the selected item active but then would not refresh the page with the language content.

I am not sure if this is the right way to do it but if anyone can think of a simplier solution that would be great.

I have added a link to my script but will not work as images and php are not included in it. Basically when the user selects the icon in the list the page is freshed and then the jQuery checks if the url has fr or en ect and if so appends the li id = french with the image onto the current span.

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/Wmb4n/7/

This works:

```
$(function() {
    var loc = document.location.href;

        if (loc.indexOf('en') > -1) {
            $("span.current").append(english);

        } else if (loc.indexOf('ru') > -1) {
            $("span.current").append(russian);

        } else if (loc.indexOf('fr') > -1) {
            $("span.current").append(french);

        } else if (loc.indexOf('de') > -1) {
            $("span.current").append(german);
        }
    });
```

To change the language translation in the anchor tag is this:

```
<?php echo anchor('fr/'.strtolower($page_info['fr_title']), 'FR'); ?>
```

Comment: are you getting anything when you do alert(document.location.href);  would like to know are u getting the prefix?

Comment: With the code i submitted as my answer and using the alert(document.location.href); i get this: http://localhost:8888/website-name/en/home and changes whatever page or language i am on. Is this right?

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/Wmb4n/8/) working for me, am I making an mistake?

Comment: Your not making a mistake,it works only it refreshes the page to the say "french langage" and then the drop down resets and the french fr isn't shown. Your code does help though :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, just want to know what to know the cause the issue that why :) Do you want to prevent the page refresh?

Comment: I need to page to refresh as the content is changing from the selected languages.When the user clicks the anchor the page is directed to the right language at the moment and only way i can get the correct language to appear is detecting the language in the url. I hope this makes sense. I did not create the language translator so i am just going off what is in the codeigniter view and controllers :)